# Play form helpers java/scala contradictions

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to set up a template which has a form, and I'd like to use the [form template helpers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFormHelpers).

According to the docs, I should be able to do:

template:

```
@import controllers.MyController.MyFormClass

@(form: Form[MyFormClass])

@helper.form(action = routes.MyController.myView()) {
    @helper.inputText(form("field1"))
    @helper.inputText(form("field2"))
}
```

Control:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    @Inject
    FormFactory formFactory;

    public Result myView() {
        final Form<MyFormClass> form = formFactory.form(MyFormClass.class).bindFromRequest();

        if (form.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(myTemplate.render(form));
        } else {
            final MyFormClass data = form.get();
            return ok("a ok");
        }
    }

    public static class MyFormClass {
        @Constraints.Required()
        @Constraints.MinLength(5)
        private String field1;

        @Constraints.Required()
        @Constraints.MinLength(10)
        private String field2;

        public MyFormClass() {}

        public void setField1(String field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }

        public String getField1() {
            return this.field1;
        }

        public void setField2(String field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        public String getField2() {
            return this.field2;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `Form` class is from the java api, and if the template expects the scala api of `Form` then there's an error in the control (`MyController`) class:

```
myTemplate.render(form)
```

complains about

> `play.api.data.Form<MyFormClass>` can not be applied to
>   `play.data.Form<MyFormClass>`

However, if in the template I import the java form:

```
@import play.data.Form
```

Then I get errors in the template:

```
@helper.inputText(form(FIELD))
```

complains about

> Cannot resolve reference inputText with such signature

I pretty much copied the example in the (java) docs, without much changes, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Any ideas?

---

#### Edit

My `build.sbt`:

```
name := "my-project-name"

version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

My `build.properties`:

```
template.uuid=SOME_UUID
sbt.version=0.13.11
```

My `plugins.sbt`:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

Comment: Please, post your build.sbt file.

Comment: It's the same as the created one, I don't think I changed it..  But I added it to my question.

Comment: This is weird. When enabling `PlayJava` the proper imports/configurations are set and so you won't have this kind of problem. Try to run `sbt clean` and remove `target` directory (and also `project/target`) and run again.

Comment: I tried the clean and removal of the target dirs, but that had no affect. But I can change the `Form` in my tamplate to `@import play.data.Form` but then  then `@helper.inputText` functions have errors.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. Could you please create and share a project that reproduces it?

Comment: Here's a [zip file with an example project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqwqHi03DR-ObKLltmbLwhS8kJs). It only contains the Controller, routes and `build.sbt`. It's based on the skeleton play app that is created using the activator.

Comment: After adding `project/plugins.sbt` and `project/build.properties` to your project, it works perfectly to me. I've used files from a clean project. Maybe you should add the content of both files to your question.

Comment: Really? That's weird. I added the files content to my question

Comment: I was really not able to reproduce your problem. How are you running the project?

Comment: I'm not running it because I have compilation errors: If I `@import play.data.Form` in my template then I get errors with the `@helper.inputText(form("fieldname"))` (error: `expected Field, actual: Form.Field`). When I don't import it, then this fails: `mytemplate.render(form)` with: `render(play.api.data.Form<...> cannot be applied to (play.data.Form<...>)`. Which form are you using? scala or java?